# Set all selected media gallery types to default store value using SOAP Api

Tags: magento-1.9, soap

I want all images of a product to use the default small_image, thumbnail and image again for every storeview using the SOAP api.

So far I've tried to set the 'types' using catalog_product_attribute_media.update to null but with no success.

```
            foreach($storeviews as $storeviewId) {
                $result = $client->call(
                    $session,
                    'catalog_product_attribute_media.list',
                    $productId,
                    $storeviewId
                );

                foreach($result as $image) {
                    $client->call(
                        $session,
                        'catalog_product_attribute_media.update',
                        [ 
                            $productId,
                            $image['file'],
                            [
                                'types' => null,
                            ]
                        ],
                        $storeviewId
                    );
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have an error in your API call, the parameter `type` needs to be an array in order to be processed correctly. If you change your code and use an empty array instead of `null` you should achieve what you want.

Anyway it's not necessary to make update calls for images which do not have any image type set. So please change the code for the second foreach loop as follows and give it a try:

```
foreach($result as $image) {
    if (count($image['types']) > 0){
        $client->call(
            $session,
            'catalog_product_attribute_media.update',
            [ 
                $productId,
                $image['file'],
                [
                   'types' => []
                ]
            ],
            $storeviewId
        );
    }
}
```